# How to add my variable every time

Tags: c#

How to add `beer` to `beersList` every time I transfer value from diffrent Form?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Beer> beersList = new List<Beer>();
        private static Beer beer;
        internal static Beer Beer
        {
            get { return beer; }
            set { beer = value; }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 ...
```

Comment: Sorry for my phrase, im newbie. I meant using this `Form1.Beer = beer;` in diffrent Form

Comment: The `bearList` member is not static, while your Property is. Which one should it be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you may do so like this:

```
        internal static Beer Beer
        {
            get { return beer; }
            set 
            { 
                beersList.Add(value);
                beer = value; 
            }
        }
```

Now each time you set a new value to the Beer property, it will be added to the list of beerList

Comment: This would not even compile based on the original code sample.